# How to use Google Cloud Translate API to translate PDF documents with php and curl

Tags: php, pdf, curl, translation, google-translation-api

I am trying to use the Google Translate API to automatically translate PDF documents and I want to use php/curl.
The code for translating text is pretty easy to handle:

```
function _translate_text(){
  $apiKey = 'myAPIKey';
  $text = 'Hello world!';
  $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=en&target=fr';
  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, "mysite"); //without this the authentication fails
  $response = curl_exec($handle);
  $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
  curl_close($handle);
  echo 'Translation: ' . var_dump($responseDecoded);
}
```

However I cannot succed to write a code that would send a PDF file and receive the translation.
It is clearly possible, as described in the [Google Translate API help](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents).

Also, if I read the documentation correctly, the PDF is sent as a stream of bytes, but the response is a document stored in cloud? Is it not possible to receive the file contents back?

Thank you very much.

Comment: *"as described in the Google Translate API help"* How about providing the link?

Comment: Link added: [Google Translate API Help](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents)

Comment: _"The response also returns a byte stream."_ - that would be the contents of your translated file then, if I am understanding the docs correctly. The file might get saved into the cloud, but you _also_ get the byte data back at the same time.

Comment: Not sure if it also returns the stream, but mote importantly: how to get the translated document and/or stream...